# choosing which main() to use in the Makefile

Tags: c, makefile

In a C project, I have a main() function in several files. When I compile I thus have an error "multiple declarations of main". Is it possible to choose in the Makefile which one of those main() functions should be used to compile ? (the other ones would then be ignored...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could hide them using the pre-processor:

In file1.c:

```
#if defined FILE1_MAIN
int main(void)
{
  printf("Running main() in file1.c");
  return 0;
}
#endif
```

This can be repeated as necessary in any number of C files.

Then have logic in the Makefile that passes the proper -D option to the compiler, i.e. -DFILE1_MAIN to include the `main()` from file1, -DFILE2_MAIN to get file2.c's, and so on.

This technique can also be useful when implementing e.g. library modules, to include an optional `main()` for testing in a single C file.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply write a target for each `main()`, where you would ignore all but one file which contains `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

You only may have one `main()` function in your source. You'll have either to rename all of the other instances, or to exclude those source files that include other instances of `main()` from the build.